# Runtime.exec won't run javac, but command line will

Tags: java, javac, runtime.exec

In my program, I create a .java file and then compile it. The command I use looks like this:

```
javac -classpath [path to main directory]\my.jar -d [path to main directory]\bin [path to main directory]\src\pkg1\MyClass.java
```

This is called with the following code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
runtime.exec(command)
```

However, when I run it by clicking "Run" in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, 
    The system cannot find the file specified
```

Now, I know what this means: I haven't installed Java correctly, and my path variable needs to include the JDK. However, the problem with that simple hypothesis is that it works perfectly fine when I use the exact same command from the command line (obviously not with `runtime.exec()`, but still). I know it's not a fault with my Java installation or with the command itself, because otherwise it wouldn't work from the command line, so what's left and how do I fix it?

Comment: you pobably need the full path. (Your PATH variable might not help if you don't use it before calling exec  )

Comment: And you should also probably make use `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. 2) See also the [`JavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

You are asking the JVM to run a command named "javac",
but it fails with an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2,
The system cannot find the file specified
```

#### Explanation

The JVM does not know where to find "javac".
Whether or not *you* are able to run "javac" yourself is separate
from whether the *JVM* can also run that command.

#### Reproducing the behavior

Here's a simple program to reproduce the behavior – it tries to run "test.sh":

```
String command = "test.sh";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("command: [" + command + "] -- " + "output: [" + br.readLine() + "]");
```

Running that code will throw an exception because
the JVM doesn't know where to find "test.sh":

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "test.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
```

#### Solution

I do in fact have "test.sh" located on my computer, but I didn't specify the full path earlier ("/var/tmp")
in the Java program.
The script is pretty simple, it just runs the "date" command:

```
% cat /var/tmp/test.sh
#!/bin/sh
date "+%Y-%m-%d"

% /var/tmp/test.sh 
2022-08-05
```

Editing the command
so that it's using an absolute path to "test.sh"
works fine:

```
String command = "/var/tmp/test.sh";

command: [/var/tmp/test.sh] -- output: [2022-08-05]
```

#### Example: same for `javac`

This works fine for "javac", too – here's the output from command
`"/usr/bin/javac -version"`:

```
command: [/usr/bin/javac -version] -- output: [javac 18.0.1.1]
```